# C++ Read getline from txt file and store into string array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, iteration, getline

I'm reading from a text file using (getline(MyFile, line))from a text file and want to store it inside a string array at each element.
My code doesn't work properly.
Basically, I need to read from a file, save each line into a string array, then iterate through each string at each element.
The for loop doesn't increase to 4 as well and I'm not sure why. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int array[16], i;
fstream myFile;
string filename, line, str[256];

int main() {

    // 1. The user will enter the full name of the file
    cout << "Enter the file name to open: ";
    cin >> filename;
    getchar();  // clear the input buffer before reading the filename

    // 2. Open the file for reading (input)
    myFile.open(filename.c_str(), fstream::in);

    // only continue if the file has opened successfully
    if (myFile.is_open() == false) {
        cout << "ERROR: not able to open " << filename << endl;
    }
    else {
        // 3. Access the file - read all the lines from the file
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            while (getline(myFile, line)) {
                str[i] = line;
                cout << "String [" << i << "] = " << str[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: how many lines are read when i == 0? Run your program under a debugger, put a breakpoint on `str[i] = line`, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 2 chages to your code to read and print all lines(<256 lines) of a text file

1.comment out the `for` statement

2.insert `i++` in while loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int array[16], i;
fstream myFile;
string filename, line, str[256];

int main() {

    // 1. The user will enter the full name of the file
    cout << "Enter the file name to open: ";
    cin >> filename;
    getchar();  // clear the input buffer before reading the filename

    // 2. Open the file for reading (input)
    myFile.open(filename.c_str(), fstream::in);

    // only continue if the file has opened successfully
    if (myFile.is_open() == false) {
        cout << "ERROR: not able to open " << filename << endl;
    }
    else {
        // 3. Access the file - read all the lines from the file
        //for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            while (getline(myFile, line)) {
                str[i] = line;
                cout << "String [" << i << "] = " << str[i] << endl;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// get used to not typing, using namespace

int main() 
{
    std::fstream myFile;
    std::string filename;
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines; // use vector instead of arrays

    // error handling in C++, is exceptions
    myFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    // 1. The user will enter the full name of the file
    std::cout << "Enter the file name to open: ";
    std::cin >> filename;
    //getchar();  // clear the input buffer before reading the filename

    // 2. Open the file for reading (input)
    try
    {
        myFile.open(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::in);
    
        // 3. Access the file - read all the lines from the file
        int count = 0;
        while (getline(myFile, line))
        {
            lines.push_back(line);
            std::cout << "String [" << count++ << "] = " << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: not able to open " << filename << " error = " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```